Upload application/octet-stream - security
I have a question about security when a user upload  an application/octet-stream file (I'm using cloudflare R2), even if the file I'm trying to upload should be a simple text/plain or object.mtl it's been uploaded as application/octet-stream, I'm a bit scared to allow upload application/octet-stream because it might be any kind of file, is there a way to make this upload secure?
